# Spark process history logs Bluemix (DSX)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, data-science-experience

I'm working with my notebook in DSX using the spark instance related to it and I can't see the spark history log. If I access from bluemix I saw the following error:

Not aouthorized
spaceGuid: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

What could be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Santiago.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Spark history logs on DSX Notebooks by accessing the `Notebook Info`->`Environment` panel on the right-hand side of the UI. There is link `View Spark History Server` which directs you to the Spark history server UI.

Comment: Thanks Sven but that doesn't work. It shows a Json showing that some error has ocurred.

Comment: Ok, strange, how old is your spark service instance ? Normally, for each spark service instance created on DSX, the link should should work. Can you please create a new spark service instance and test the Spark History server again for the new instance ?

Can you please post the error message as well ?